# Why Chrome doesn't respect the margin properly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

I search for a long and I can't find an answer :/

In Chrome (Internet Explorer, Konqueror, and many others) the `h1` margin at bottom is added to `.blue`. However, Firefox respect the css rules properly.

Any suggestion?

**HTML**

```
<div class="red"><div class="blue"><h1>Hello World!</h1></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
  background: red;
  /* All this contain margins */
  float:left;
  /* padding-top:1px; */
  /* display: inline-block */
  /* overflow: hidden */
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
  min-height: 60px;
}

h1{
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

**Gecko-based:** [This one is the correct, I guess]

[image]

**Webkit-based, KHTML-based and Trident shell:**

[image]

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/marquex/pen/fzsIk

Comment: This seems to work fine in Chrome for me...

Comment: @jwddixon could you add more info, please. All people I asked to check the conditions told me that it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVING**

After a long search I reported the issue on chromium repo. And they accept it as a **bug**. So, if anyone wants to know the final of this history can follow the fix process [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362427).
Thanks anyone who try to help us, but let me add that I did not believe that Stackoverflow can be able to not see an error of this magnitude. I am a little less *stackoverflowita*.

Answer (score 2):

The margin issue you are having is related with the `min-height` rule in the `.blue` div. Replace it for a `height` rule if it is possible to get the same result in Chrome and Firefox.

I have no idea why that is happening when using `min-height` though. Maybe is some kind of Chrome's bug.

Comment: Thanks but I can't avoid min-height

Answer (score 1):

Define your fonts, this is the problem, every browser have different settings for default fonts, headings (h1...h6) respectively. So the actual height of the text in `h1` will be different and *this is the cause for different margins at bottom/top*.

As you can see, Gecko-based browser uses a sort of `Garamond`-styled font, all other use **by default** `Times New Roman`, of course if user was predefined the fonts for pages, sometimes everything may look the same across all browsers, example:

```
h1{
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  background: green;
  font-family: "Your-favorite-font", Times, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```