# Why does Chrome not respects negative margin in this case?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

I having problems with a very simple code.

Looks like Chrome is ignoring the  negative `margin-bottom` I'm using. In IE11 works as expected.

IE 11

[image: How it render in IE11]

Chrome 38

[image: How it render in Chrome 38]

I just want to align them. I know I can achieve with more code but I'm wondering if I'm expecting `margin-bottom` work different than it should work:

```
<div id="main">
    <select>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
    <button></button>
    <select id="AmbientesSelect">
        <option value="TEST">TESTE</option>
    </select>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#main {
    background-color:red;
}
#main button {
    width: 28px;
    height: 23px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}
```

Live reproduction: http://jsfiddle.net/v4bd7xjy/2/

I've searched some question but they are too specific or too different. Some of them:

[Why Chrome doesn't respect the margin properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910158/why-chrome-doesnt-respect-the-margin-properly)

[Negative margin-bottom rendering not correctly in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637844/negative-margin-bottom-rendering-not-correctly-in-chrome)

[How do negative margins in CSS work and why is (margin-top:-5 != margin-bottom:5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5)

**Edit**

If that matter I filled a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403297&q=canova&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) report on Chromium project.

Comment: I'd user vertical alignment and floats to unify the alignment, removing any padding and margins as needed. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gkndebpn/

Comment: I agree with @j08691, or you can try position:relative; top:7px; to nudge them down a bit.

Comment: @j08691 Well, it worked. But `margin-bottom` should work inthat way, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try add to your button `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Well, it did the trick, but did not explain if the `margin-bottom` should work in the way it is or not. But thank's

Comment: I think it's because of bug in chrome. There is no problem when there is some text in `<button>` tag - default `vertical-align` is `baseline` and both elements _content_ baselines are aligned to parent baseline (try to add some text to button and see). Problem appears when there is no content in `<button>` tag. Chrome then (wrongly) assuming that `<button>` baseline is the same as button bottom and aligning its bottom to parent baseline. Using `vertical-align: top` (or `vertical-align: bottom`) aligning all elements tops (or bottoms) to the top (or bottom) of entire line.

Comment: I think `margin-bottom` is not working, because baseline of text in button is not changing upon margin change.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar Problem, in my case chrome doesn't recognize the correct dimension of the parent element.

```
<li>
  <span></span>
</li>

li {
  position: absolute;
}
span {
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

display:block; does it for me...

```
span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```